# Deployment Manager: Operation failed because another operation was already in progress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-deployment-manager

I want to create two databases in one cloudsql instance.
But if it is written in the following way it will result in an error.

```
resources:
- name: test-instance
  type: sqladmin.v1beta4.instance
  properties:
    region: us-central
    backendType: SECOND_GEN
    instanceType: CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE
    settings:
      tier: db-f1-micro
- name: test_db1
  type: sqladmin.v1beta4.database
  properties:
    instance: $(ref.test-instance.name)
    charset: utf8mb4
    collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
- name: test_db2
  type: sqladmin.v1beta4.database
  properties
    instance: $(ref.test-instance.name)
    charset: utf8mb4
    collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
```

output:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in Operation 
[operation-********]
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/sample-deploy/resources/test_db2
   message:
'{"ResourceType":"sqladmin.v1beta4.database","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Operation
    failed because another operation was already in progress.","reason":"operationInProgress"}],"message":"Operation
    failed because another operation was already in progress.","statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/****/instances/test-instance/databases","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

Please tell me what to do to resolve the error.

Answer (score 2):

The error “ResourceErrorCode” is an error which originates with the [CloudSQL API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/databases/insert).

The issue here is that Deployment Manager will try to run all resource modifications in parallel (unless you specify a dependency between resources). Deployment Manager is a declarative configuration, it will run the deployments in parallel either they are independent of each other or not.

In this specific case, CloudSQL is not able to create two databases at the same time. This is why you are seeing the error message: `Operation failed because another operation was already in progress`.

There can be only one pending operation at a given point of time because of the inherent system architecture. This is a limitation on the concurrent writes to a CloudSQL database.

To resolve this issue, you will have to create the two databases in sequence, not in parallel.

For more information on how to do so, you may consult [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/using-references) on this matter.